# Are geotiffs with the embedded georeferencing information supported?

Tags: postgis-2.0

I am able to load raster data into my postrgreSQL data base however when I display in Quantum GIS the pixel height and width of the image is being translated into real world lat/lon coordinates, as a result my image appears 1000 degrees wide and 600 degrees high which is obviously wrong. The Image I am loading is a geotiff ie the coordinate header is embedded in the file rather than a world file.

I am using the following combination of database and software:

Quantum GIS 1.8.0
Postgis 2.0
PostgreSQL 9.1

Can anyone elaborate or point me in the direction of an explanation of how to get the image to load correctly?

**Update:**

This is now working for me as I have tried loading using a tiff file which includes the separate world file (.tfw). So I take it geotiffs with the embedded georeferencing information are not supported?